# Laravel serialize object to array with foreign keys

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    public function country(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Country::class,'country_id');
    }
}

$customer = Customer::Find(1);
```

when doing `$customer->toArray()` it will serialize 'country_id' and not the entire country object.

Is it possible that country object will be serialized as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load country relation ship explicitly,

```
$customer = Customer::findOrFail(1)->load('country');

$customer->toArray()
```

another way of doing is this by using `with`

```
$customers = Customer::with('country')->find(1)->toArray();
```

If you want to load one or more relationship always, then you can specify them in the `protected $with` property in the model, so the relationships are always eager loaded,

eg:

```
  protected $with = ['country'];
```